# How long does one have to pay the $150 per month subscription fee for Unity pro?

Tags: unity

I'm a bit confused by how the subscription for Unity Pro works. If I were to get Unity Pro, do I have to keep paying $150 per month for as long as I'm using Unity pro? Or do I have to keep paying $150 per month until certain period, after which I am no longer required to pay anything?

Furthermore, if I developed a game with the personal version of Unity and the game made over $100K, would that result in an immediate penalty or will Unity give me a deadline before which I must get Unity Plus/Pro?

Answer (score 4):

> How long does one have to pay the $150 per month subscription fee for Unity pro?

The [Unity store](https://store.unity.com/) currently only offers *annual* plans, either paid monthly or paid yearly. Assuming you cancelled the renewal before the end of your annual plan, it's 12 months after you purchased your license.

> If I were to get Unity Pro, do I have to keep paying $150 per month for as long as I'm using Unity pro?

You need to pay until your contract ends, one year after you purchased your license. Before the license automatically renews, you need to decide if you still want to use it. If you still want to use Unity Pro, you'll start another contract of 12 months.

Now let's tweak this question a bit:

> If I were to get Unity Pro, do I have to keep paying $150 per month for as long as I'm using Unity?

No, you pay until your subscription plan ends, then, as described above, you're free to cancel the plan (*before* the automatic renewal occurs) unless you still use Unity (for anything) *and* your company has more than 100k revenue. If you did not make 100k in revenue in the previous 12 months, you *can* downgrade to Unity Personal for free (or to Unity Plus if you made less than 200k).

> Or do I have to keep paying $150 per month until certain period, after which I am no longer required to pay anything?

The $150 per month payments that you are required to do are when you subscribe to the *1 year, paid monthly* plan, or that your subscription ends *and* you chose not to renew. As previously said, you're no longer required to pay anything if your subscription plan ends, and you don't work with Unity or you don't make more than 100/200k a year.

> Furthermore, if I developed a game with the personal version of Unity and the game made over $100K, would that result in an immediate penalty or will Unity give me a deadline before which I must get Unity Plus/Pro?

The [documentation](https://store.unity.com/#plans-individual) is not very clear about this, but you can assume that as soon as you've made 100k based off you using Unity in the previous 12 months, you need to upgrade to a paid plan.

---

If you made your game in year one using Unity Personal, and your game had a big success and you made 100k during that first year, and you still want to push updates to your players, even if you plan that it's your last game and you quit gamedev after that, you're forced to buy the Pro license, at least for one year.

Answer (score 2):

## Its a subscription and you can't cancel

From the [FAQ](https://store.unity.com/products/unity-pro):

> #### Can I cancel my subscription before the end of my commitment period?
>
> There is no cancellation policy or reimbursement for a subscription. Once you commit to a subscription you are obligated to pay all monthly payments owing.

Note that this is based on the *commitment period,* i.e. if you say "I'll pay for a year" you pay for a year. After that, you will move to the flex plan.

> #### Will my subscription automatically renew?
>
> For Pro subscribers, when your commitment period ends your plan will automatically convert to a flexible month-to-month subscription. The key things to note about the flex option:
>
> - You pay month-to-month and can cancel your subscription at any time. However, cancellation will take effect from the following month.
> - If you choose to expire your plan, your version of Unity will switch to Personal.

Additionally, from the [Personal FAQ](https://store.unity.com/products/unity-personal):

> #### Can I use Personal for commercial development?
>
> If you or your company currently makes more than $100k in annual gross revenues or has raised funds in excess of $100k, you are not permitted to use Unity Personal, for prototyping or otherwise, as defined in our EULA Agreement.
>
> You may use Unity Plus for up to $200k in annual gross revenues, or Unity Pro with an unlimited revenue or fundraising capacity.

This means that if you make a game, and then earn $100k in revenue from it, you are obligated to purchase a Plus or Pro license.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually what the question is asking about. If I made a game in Unity two years ago which I don't update anymore but still sell, do I still need to pay for my Unity license? And will Unity's lawyers show up at my doorstep the day my revenue hits $100,000.01 or do I get a grace period?

Comment: @Philipp Neither of those questions are stated by the asker. For the former, no, you can cancel any time during the flex period (anything built with Pro before then is considered "built with Pro" and not subject to the 100k). As for the "grace period" it isn't stated. I suspect that Unity won't do anything until they find out, then send you an email or letter saying, "Hey, we noticed, you should buy Pro" as a courtesy reminder. If you still don't, that's when they'd start official legal action (this is, however, only speculation). Unity does not detail their exact procedures in this regard.

Comment: @Draco18s I feel like your missed the point of the question. I wasn't asking about cancelling. I wanted to know how long the payment part of the Unity Pro subscription lasts. This is because I vaguely remember that a few years ago you had to pay for Unity Pro monthly for only a certain period of time.

Comment: @User95 Forever. There is no "convert to owning the software without making payments" clause. You pay monthly or you go Personal. This is covered by the sections of the FAQ I quoted: *`If you choose to expire your plan, your version of Unity will switch to Personal.`*

Comment: @Draco18s Are you sure it's "forever" (If that's the case it's a good reason to NOT use Unity at all)?
Maybe you can cite some sources? I vaguely remember researching this topic 1 or 2 years ago and seeing answer somewhere that you need to pay 2 years straight and then you're no longer obligated to pay. I find it very alarming that on the Unity site\faq this very important detail isn't clarified in any way. "Paying forever" is a really vague and weird scheme that any sane person would want to avoid.

Comment: @Svargr Unity changed their business model several times in the past years.

Comment: @Svargr Its a subscription model. For paying for Unity you get free upgrades to the latest version. And as Philipp says, they've changed their business model a few times. Personal (the ostensibly free version) is "good enough" for people like you and me that make small games that never get much revenue. Professional is for businesses like Deloitte and Comcast that the $125/mo. per seat price tag is just the cost of doing business.

Comment: FWIW, this answer contains outdated information.