# Several questions about Unity license and revenue from games

Tags: unity, licensing, monetization, revenue, microtransactions

So, what I know is if I'm using Unity Personal Edition and start earning more than $100,000 I need to upgrade to Plus or Pro, but I have some questions:

1. If revenue from the game reached more than $100,000, but after a few months it dropped and now it's much less than $100,000, can I "downgrade" (go back) to the Personal Edition?
2. Does revenue from ads count?
3. Does revenue from microtransactions count (buying in-game items)?
4. If revenue from in-game ads counts, what's with ads on the web page where you download the game? Do these also count as my revenue from the game?
5. Does revenue from merch, soundtrack and things like that count?
6. If I "downgraded" from Plus or Pro to the Personal Edition, do I have to remove games made with Plus or Pro from e.g. Steam, Epic, GameJolt? If not, do I have to update the game with Personal Edition (so the game has Unity logo again)?
7. If my revenue is more than $100,000, but I stopped using Unity, do I have to still pay?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this question is worth a downvote. Unity license stuff is not _that_ trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If revenue from the game reached more than $100,000, but after a few months it dropped and now it's much less than $100,000, can I "downgrade" (go back) to the Personal Edition?

You can downgrade once you have reached the end of your plan. This is covered here: [How long does one have to pay the $125 per month subscription fee for Unity pro?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173658/how-long-does-one-have-to-pay-the-125-per-month-subscription-fee-for-unity-pro).

> Does revenue from ads count?

It is *all revenue* (from the [Unity Personal](https://store.unity.com/products/unity-personal) page: "Eligibility: Unity Personal is for individuals, hobbyists, and small organizations with less than $100K of revenue or funds raised in the last 12 months."). This means that if your aunt gave you 50k to start your company, and the government gave you 49k to start your company, and you made 1k in revenue from ads on your web site, you need to upgrade.

> Does revenue from microtransactions count (buying in-game items)?

Yes.

> If revenue from in-game ads counts, what's with ads on the web page where you download the game? Do these also count as my revenue from the game?

It's all revenue, not only from a single game.

> Does revenue from merch, soundtrack and things like that count?

Yes.

> If I "downgraded" from Plus or Pro to the Personal Edition, do I have to remove games made with Plus or Pro from e.g. Steam, Epic, GameJolt? If not, do I have to update the game with Personal Edition (so the game has Unity logo again)?

No, you don't have to remove them, and you do not have to "downgrade" them.

> If my revenue is more than $100,000, but I stopped using Unity, do I have to still pay?

You still need to pay until the end of your plan. This is also covered by the question linked above.